# how to find count of active sellers from transaction table

Tags: sql, sql-server

from the table given below find the count of active sellers for each day in June 2017. A seller is considered active when he has listed  at least one item in last 30 days from the transaction date.

sample table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, one method is to generate the dates and use a lateral join to calculate the number of sellers:

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2017-06-01' as date) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < '2017-06-30'
     )
select d.dte, t.num_sellers
from dates d outer apply
     (select count(distinct t.seller_id) as num_sellers
      from t
      where t.transaction_date > dateadd(day, -30, d.dte) and
            t.transaction_date <= d.dte
     ) t
order by d.dte;
```